# Limit of the ratio of two divergent sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, divergent-series

Let $∑a_n $ be a series of real numbers which converges, but not absolutely.

Let $ p_n = \frac{a_n +|a_n|}{2} \ge 0, \ q_n = \frac{a_n - |a_n|}{2} \  \le 0 $.

Let $ P_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}{p_k}, \ Q_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}{q_k} $.

Show that ${ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{Q_n}{P_n} } = -1$.

I was able to show that both  $ {Q_n}  $ and $ {P_n} $  diverges. But I couldn't proof the ratio between them (I'm not sure if it's helpful).
How can it be proofed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$P_n + Q_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$$ so
$$ 1+ \frac{Q_n}{P_n}  = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k}{P_n} \rightarrow \frac{const.}{\infty} = 0 $$

Comment: Thanks. but does the fact that we add "1" to the ratio of the sequences change our original problem? I mean we prove that 1 + qn/pn goes to 0, but we know nothing about qn/pn...

Comment: We just subtract 1 from both sides. The limit of a sum is a sum of the limits, in this case $$ 0 = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{Q_n}{P_n}) = (\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}1)+(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{Q_n}{P_n}) = 1+ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{Q_n}{P_n}$$

Comment: Thanks! It might be out of this question's scope, but how do we show that $P_n$ necessarily goes to infinity?  Is it enough to say the the series $P_n$ is monotonically increasing and diverges?

Comment: Yes that is enough. If it were monotonically increasing and bounded, then it would be convergent.